# Determine number of comment lines in T-SQL Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have found numerous code examples for determining the number of lines of code within a Stored Procedure (or function, etc).

I am looking for a way to approximate the number of comment lines. I know there are line/block comments and techncially I don't want to count lines of code with line comments on them....but I might if I can get a close approximation.

Is there a simple way of doing this? or do I have to count the number of "--" instance and "/* */" pairing within a definition?

Comment: Please provide an example of lines you want to count.

Comment: Especially fun if you need to take into account that those characters can perfectly legitimately appear within a string literal and aren't a comment. And multi-line string literals are perfectly possible too.

Comment: Are you trying to do this exclusively in TSQL? Have you looked at `TSqlParser` instead?

Comment: Gordon: that would be lines that are line comments starting with -- or block comments (bounded by ?* and */)   Damien: Yeah I know...  Martin: If you are talking the Microsoft class I'm not sure how that will help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for - [A way to find the Real Total Lines of T-SQL Code in a SQL Database](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/paulmcmillan/archive/2012/01/03/a-way-to-find-the-real-total-lines-of-t-sql-code-in-a-sql-database.aspx)

I understand it is not exactly what you are looking for, but should be fairly straight forward to update to your needs.

Comment: No, I took a look at that prior to posting.